# Tensorflow GPU long startup time

Tags: tensorflow, time, gpu, startup, rtx

I have this problem I know quite a lot of people heard about. I upgraded from my laptop with GTX 1050 Ti to a PC with RTX 3060 Ti. I'm running everything in an Anaconda Virtual Environment. I've copied my env from the laptop to the PC. Now the TensorFlow GPU takes a lot of time to start up. Even if I write the 2 lines of code:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

It takes a lot of time (more than 30 minutes). The same thing works perfectly on my laptop with GTX 1050 Ti.
I tried a lot of stuff:

- reinstalling every package in another environment (of course, same versions - I am using TF 2.1, cudnn 7.6.5, cudatoolkit 10.1.243).
- putting some lines of code before my program (I tried more than 10 different possibilities).
- reinstalling clean the GPU drivers.

After TensorFlow starts up, the RTX 3060 Ti is working properly, training very fast.
I googled a lot, but I see that there are still a lot of people in my place right now, so I'm not expecting an answer pretty soon:).

Anyways, if someone manages to find an answer, please share it with me! Thanks in advance and have a great day!

P.S. If you need code or console logs, here you go. I've written a quick MNIST program:

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

# Load and prepare the train and test set
def load_dataset():
    # Load the dataset
    (trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = mnist.load_data()
    # Reshape the dataset to have a single channel
    trainX = trainX.reshape((trainX.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
    testX = testX.reshape((testX.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
    # One hot encode target values
    trainY = to_categorical(trainY)
    testY = to_categorical(testY)
    return trainX, trainY, testX, testY

# Scale pixels
def prep_pixels(train, test):
    # Convert from integers to float
    train_norm = train.astype('float32')
    test_norm = test.astype('float32')
    # Normalize to range 0-1
    train_norm = train_norm / 255.0
    test_norm = test_norm / 255.0
    return train_norm, test_norm

# Define the CNN classifier
def define_classifier():
    # Build the structure
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (28, 28, 1)))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
    classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    classifier.add(Flatten())
    classifier.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))
    # Compile the model
    classifier.compile(optimizer = SGD(lr = 0.01, momentum = 0.9), loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                       metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier

# Evaluate the classifier using the K-Fold Cross-Validation
def evaluate_classifier(dataX, dataY, n_folds = 5):
    scores, histories = list(), list()
    # Prepare Cross-Validation
    kfold = KFold(n_folds, shuffle = True, random_state = 1)
    # Enumerate splits
    for trainX_i, testX_i in kfold.split(dataX):
        # Define classifier
        classifier = define_classifier()
        # Select rows for train and test
        trainX, trainY, testX, testY = dataX[trainX_i], dataY[trainX_i], dataX[testX_i], dataY[testX_i]
        # Fit the classifier
        history = classifier.fit(trainX, trainY, batch_size = 32, epochs = 10, 
                                 validation_data = (testX, testY), verbose = 1)
        # Evaluate the classifier
        _, acc = classifier.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose = 1)
        print('> ACC: %.3f' % (acc * 100.0))
        # Store history, accuracy
        scores.append(acc)
        histories.append(history)
    return scores, histories

# Plot learning curves
def visualise_learning(histories):
    for i in range(len(histories)):
        plt.tight_layout()
        # Plot LOSS
        plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
        plt.title('Cross-Entropy Loss')
        plt.plot(histories[i].history['loss'], color = 'blue', label = 'train')
        plt.plot(histories[i].history['val_loss'], color = 'orange', label = 'test')
        # Plot ACCURACY
        plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
        plt.title('Classification Accuracy')
        plt.plot(histories[i].history['accuracy'], color = 'blue', label = 'train')
        plt.plot(histories[i].history['val_accuracy'], color = 'orange', label = 'test')
    plt.show()

# Summarize classifier performance
def summarize_performance(scores):
    print('Accuracy: mean=%.3f std=%.3f, n=%d' % (mean(scores) * 100, std(scores) * 100, len(scores)))
    
# Run all parts together
def run():
    trainX, trainY, testX, testY = load_dataset()
    trainX, testX = prep_pixels(trainX, testX)
    scores, histories = evaluate_classifier(trainX, trainY)
    visualise_learning(histories)
    summarize_performance(scores)
  
def save_model():
    trainX, trainY, testX, testY = load_dataset()
    trainX, testX = prep_pixels(trainX, testX)
    classifier = define_classifier()
    classifier.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs = 25, batch_size = 32, verbose = 1)
    classifier.save('final_classifier.h5')
    
##############################################################################################################

# make a prediction for a new image.
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

# load and prepare the image
def load_image(filename):
    # load the image
    img = load_img(filename, grayscale=True, target_size=(28, 28))
    # convert to array
    img = img_to_array(img)
    # reshape into a single sample with 1 channel
    img = img.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
    # prepare pixel data
    img = img.astype('float32')
    img = img / 255.0
    return img

# load an image and predict the class
def run_example():
    # load the image
    img = load_image('image.png')
    # load model
    model = load_model('final_classifier.h5')
    # predict the class
    digit = model.predict_classes(img)
    print(digit[0])

# entry point, run the example
#run_example()
run()
```

And here is the console log:

```
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 17:10:11) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runcell(0, 'C:/Python/Projects/Handwritten Digit Recognition/digit_recognizer.py')

2021-01-14 13:47:28.396292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll

2021-01-14 13:47:28.396292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.018731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041720: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041751: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll

2021-01-14 13:47:28.396292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.018731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041720: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041751: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.395981: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.430370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.452057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.659034: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.837570: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.055598: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.056116: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0

2021-01-14 13:47:28.396292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.018731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041720: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041751: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.395981: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.430370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.452057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.659034: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.837570: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.055598: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.056116: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-14 13:47:32.652696: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655023: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655039: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655046: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655051: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655062: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655067: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655072: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0

2021-01-14 13:47:28.396292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.018731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041720: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041751: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.395981: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.430370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.452057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.659034: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.837570: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.055598: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.056116: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-14 13:47:32.652696: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655023: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655039: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655046: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655051: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655062: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655067: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655072: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-14 13:50:57.038023: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-01-14 13:50:57.038040: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2021-01-14 13:50:57.038045: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2021-01-14 13:50:57.039526: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6699 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
Train on 48000 samples, validate on 12000 samples
Epoch 1/10

2021-01-14 13:47:28.396292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.018731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041720: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041751: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.395981: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.430370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.452057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.659034: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.837570: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.055598: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.056116: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-14 13:47:32.652696: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655023: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655039: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655046: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655051: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655062: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655067: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655072: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-14 13:50:57.038023: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-01-14 13:50:57.038040: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2021-01-14 13:50:57.038045: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2021-01-14 13:50:57.039526: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6699 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-01-14 13:50:57.563527: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll

2021-01-14 13:47:28.396292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.018731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041720: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041751: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.395981: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.430370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.452057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.659034: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.837570: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.055598: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.056116: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-14 13:47:32.652696: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655023: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655039: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655046: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655051: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655062: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655067: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655072: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-14 13:50:57.038023: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-01-14 13:50:57.038040: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2021-01-14 13:50:57.038045: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2021-01-14 13:50:57.039526: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6699 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-01-14 13:50:57.563527: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:52:17.763274: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
 7232/48000 [===>..........................] - ETA: 1:21:26 - loss: 2.3010 - accuracy: 0.1114  
2021-01-14 13:47:28.396292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.018731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041720: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 13:47:31.041751: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.395981: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.430370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.452057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.659034: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:31.837570: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.055598: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.056116: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-14 13:47:32.652696: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655023: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655039: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655046: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655051: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655062: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655067: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655072: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-14 13:47:32.655095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-14 13:50:57.038023: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-01-14 13:50:57.038040: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2021-01-14 13:50:57.038045: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2021-01-14 13:50:57.039526: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6699 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-01-14 13:50:57.563527: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-14 13:52:17.763274: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-14 14:05:23.645822: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:312] Internal: Invoking GPU asm compilation is supported on Cuda non-Windows platforms only
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
48000/48000 [==============================] - 869s 18ms/sample - loss: 2.3019 - accuracy: 0.1101 - val_loss: 2.3014 - val_accuracy: 0.1144
```

It took a lot of time after the lines "Adding visible gpu devices: 0" and openning the dynamic libraries after that.

Comment: An educated guess: As CUDA 10.x and associated libraries do not include Ampere binaries, a lot of code is JIT-compiled from the included PTX intermediate format into Ampere machine code.

Comment: @njuffa So do I need to change CUDA version (and therefore cudnn)? If yes, which version does support ampere gpus? Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Note that there may be strict dependencies between Tensorflow and CUDNN versions. I don't use Tensorflow and know nothing about them, but you would want to research this first. The CUDNN support matrix can be found here: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/support-matrix/index.html

Comment: Thank you for that link! It seems like only versions above 11.0 support ampere gpus. I’ll research which tensorflow version is compatible with it and I will come tomorrow with a response (currently 11PM in my country). I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please note that this is a Q&A site, not a forum with discussion threads. I personally consider this question off-topic, as it is not a programming question, but a software configuration question.

Comment: It helped, I've done it and it works just fine. If you want you can post an answer and I'll mark it as the best and then close this question.

Comment: Hi, if you are still facing a problem then maybe you can find your solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462347/tensorflow-1-14-performance-issue-on-rtx-3090

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GTX 1050 Ti` cards are based on `Pascal` architecture for which compatible `CUDA version start with 8.x`, where as `RTX 3060 Ti` cards are based on the `Ampere` architecture for which compatible `CUDA version start with 11.x`.

So compatible tensorflow version for your gpu card is `2.4.0` and cuDNN is `8.0`.

Thank you njuffa for the [CUDNN support matrix](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/support-matrix/index.html) and insights. You can check tensorflow tested build configurations for [windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) and [Linux](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).